# How to modify an external xml file and save it locally in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I'm new to C# and want to manipulate a external xml file. Here is that file:

```
<results>
     <root />
     <category id="" title="" />
     <category />
     <category />
</results>
```

I want this to be modified something like:

```
<results>
    <root />
    <categories>
        <category id="" title=""/>
        <category />
        <category />
    </categories>
</results>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, it replaces all of the elements named `category` found directly under the root element (root element is `results`) and adds new element named `categories`. `category` elements are then added to `categories` and `category` elements are removed from under the `results` element. In the end `categories` element is added. You can also save the document by calling it's `Save` method:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");

        var categoriesElement = new XElement("categories");

        var categoryElements = doc.Root.Elements("category");
        foreach(var el in categoryElements.ToList())
        {
            categoriesElement.Add(new XElement(el));
            el.Remove();

        }

        doc.Element("results").Add(categoriesElement);
        //doc.Save(<filepath>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xml);
        elem = new XElement("results",
             new XElement("root", elem.Element("root").Value),
             new XElement("categories", elem.Descendants("category"))
            );
```

Comment: Please improve your answer this will not help

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the xml can be transformed using xslt. Basics on xslt transforation can be found below,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Using xslt makes you solution or code more managable. Hope this helps